# Prove that $K \ast f \in W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb R)$ if $K \in BV(\mathbb R)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $f \in L^1 \cap L^\infty(\mathbb R)$ and $K \in BV(\mathbb R)$. Do these assumptions suffice to prove that for the convolution $K \ast f$ we have that $$K \ast f \in W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb R)$$ holds?

From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005169/is-the-convolution-by-bv-function-a-bv-function), I know that this convolution is BV, but is it true that it is also $W^{1,\infty}$?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use that for $g\in L^p(\mathbf{R})$,
\begin{align*}
\|\tau_h g-g\|_p\lesssim |h|,
\end{align*}
characterizes elements $g$ of $W^{1,p}(\mathbf{R})$ for $p>1$ and elements of $BV(\mathbf{R})$ for $p=1$. In your case you have for $h\in\mathbf{R}$, by Young's inequality (which boils down to Hölder's with the exponents involved here)
\begin{align*}
\|\tau_h (f\star K)-f\star K\|_\infty = \|f\star(\tau_h K-K)\|_\infty \leq \|f\|_\infty \|\tau_h K-K\|_1 \lesssim\|f\|_\infty |h|.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you! Could you make the Lipschitz constant in the last inequality explicit?

Comment: Well it should be $|K'|(\mathbf{R})$.

Comment: What does it denote? The total variation of $K$?

Comment: Yes. If $K\in W^{1,1}(\mathbf{R})$, it would be $\|K'\|_1$

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality $K$ is bounded increasing left-continuous, then $K(x)=m(-\infty,x)$ for a bounded non-negative measure $m$. We have by Fubini theorem$$(K*f)(x)=\int K(y)f(x-y)dy=\int\int\mathbf{1}(z<y) f(x-y)dm(z) dy\\=
\int dm(z) \int_z^\infty f(x-y)dy=\int dm(z)\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t-z)dt=\int_{-\infty}^xdt\int f(t-z)dm(z)$$
is an "antiderivative" of a bounded $L^1$ function $x\to \int f(x-z)dm(z)$.

Comment: The function $h(x):=\int f(x-z)dm(z)$ is essentially bounded (since $f$ is bounded and $m$ is a bounded measure). Thus $\int_{-\infty}^x h(t)dt$ is Lipschitz in $x$.

Comment: Thank you. I put the quesiton on the second derivative in a separate post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380772/is-f-ast-k-in-l1-mathbb-r-where-f-in-l1-cap-l-infty-mathbb-r